# laravel timestamps()

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

В `$table->timestamps();` создает два поля: **create_at** , **update_at**. Но они по дефолту равны 0.Мне нужно по дефолту вводить настоящее дату и время. Как сделать CurrentTimestamp?

Comment: Они равны 0 только в том случае, если ты самостоятельно добавляешь запись в БД. Если ты инициализируешь модель и сохранишь её в БД, то поля будут работать корректно.

Comment: @Alexxosipov понял круто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По стандарту Laravel, `timestamps` сохраняют текущую дату и время, при условии, что код написан по стандарту фреймворка. Пример:

```
$model= new Model;
$model->{{table->listname}} = $variable1;
$model->{{table->listname}} = $variable2;
$model->save();
```

Функция `save()` сохраняет текущее значение даты и времени в БД.